Why the program built with Mingw cannot be run?
Suppose we open a cmd window and enter into the Mingw bin directory to build a hello world program in another directory:
cd c:\mingw\bin
g++ -o c:\test\app.exe c:\test\app.cpp

The compiling is ok and app.exe is successfully generated, but when running it, the system pops up a windows saying:
This app can't run on your PC
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.

And there is a message "Access is denied" in the cmd window. The error persists if I copy app.exe from C:\test\ to C:\mingw\bin\ and run it. If I copy the source code app.cpp from C:\test\ to C:\mingw\bin and compile it, the built app.exe can be run without a problem. Why?
The source code(app.cpp) is very simple:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}

